# The meaning of "reserve of living"

Tags: expressions, prepositions, meaning-in-context

What might be the meaning of the phrase "reserve of living"
The quotation comes from [Maeve Gilmore's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maeve_Gilmore), *A World Away*.

> How foreign to the spirit's early beauty
>   And to the amoral integrity of the mind
>   And to all those whose **reserve of living** is lovely
>   Are the tired creeds that can be so unkind
>   [...]

It is this "reserve of living" what troubles me. I am not sure if "reserve of living" might mean "to keep one's living to oneself", in the sense of not living life as most people do, to remain uninvolved, to refrain from life...

PS. I am not a native speaker and I do not know what this "of" does to the "reserve".

Comment: Apparently it was written by Mervy Peake (http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=N-qd868ZNtQC&lpg=PA105&ots=PlhkWTsxK6&dq=How%20foreign%20to%20the%20spirit's%20early%20beauty%20%2F%20And%20to%20the%20amoral%20integrity%20of%20the%20mind%20%2F%20And%20to%20all%20those%20whose%20reserve%20of%20living%20is%20lovely%2F%20Are%20the%20creeds%20that%20can%20be%20so%20unkind&pg=PA105#v=onepage&q=How%20foreign%20to%20the%20spirit's%20early%20beauty%20/%20And%20to%20the%20amoral%20integrity%20of%20the%20mind%20/%20And%20to%20all%20those%20whose%20reserve%20of%20living%20is%20lovely&f=false)

Comment: Yes it was. I am not sure if  "reserve of living" might mean "to keep one's living to oneself", in the sense of not living life as most people do, to remain uninvolved, to refrain from life...PS. I am not a native speaker and I do not know what this "of" does to the "reserve".

Comment: Can anyone cite the precise source? There are a couple of references on line, one with a question mark after the third line, which doesn't make sense. Even as a native speaker I'm not sure whether the sense is 'a way of living held in reserve by a person' or 'an allotted span of life given by a supreme deity'. It would be useful to see the larger context in which the lines appear.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the quotation and reference for everyone to see.

Comment: How foreign to the spirit's early beauty/And to the amoral integrity of the mind/And to all those whose reserve of living is lovely/Are the tired Creeds that can be so unkind./There is brotherhood among the kindly,/Close and defter and more integral/Than any brotherhood of aisle or coven/For love rang out  befire the chapel bell./There is no intolerance and no bitterness/As between sects where the full-hearted are/And to pray for the non-natural and to have pity/On those of alien faith  whose eyes are clear/Is to be insolent, is to be ignorant,/Is to deny the god-head - is to withold/

Comment: The focal Christ of love;is to renounce/The only selfless language in the world.

Comment: The quotation is from Maeve Gilmore's A World Away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reserve as a noun, according to the American Heritage Dictionary, 4e, first definition: "Something kept back or saved for future use or a special purpose" (think "reservoir"). This only partly reveals Gilmore's meaning, but at least "reservoir of [substance]" makes logical and grammatical sense. How to comprehend "reserve of living" as "lovely" may be the poet's challenge/offering to the reader.